# Blank CMD windows when running Bat files

Tags: c#, cmd

Hey so I've been dealing with this issue for a while.  So, part of my program requires me to access Adb (android development bridge) and I do that through cmd prompt and bat files.  The problem is my when running my program a blank CMD window comes up when it comes time to execute the bat, and the bat won't execute until I close the CMD window.  ANy ideas why?

Here's what I tried:

```
 Process compiler = new Process();
        compiler.StartInfo.FileName = "push.bat";

        compiler.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        compiler.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        compiler.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;

        compiler.Start();
        string d = compiler.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        MessageBox.Show(d);
```

Blank CMD window.  I also tried this

```
    Process compiler = new Process();
        compiler.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        compiler.StartInfo.Arguments = " /c push.bat";
        compiler.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        compiler.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        compiler.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;

        compiler.Start();
        string d = compiler.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        MessageBox.Show(d);
```

Still empty CMD window with blinking cursor comes up that won't do anything until I close it.

Comment: Why did you name a _Process_ as _compiler_ ? This may be irrelevant but its just weird. It's like calling a FileReader an _Interpreter_ or a BufferedReader a _JITCompiler_.

Comment: idk just a random name..I do that often

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what's happening is that you are reading until the stream closes, but it doesn't close until `push.bat` exits.

Try using the [OutputDataReceived](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.outputdatareceived.aspx) and [ErrorDataReceived](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.errordatareceived.aspx) events and the `WaitForExit()` method.

This will let you asynchronously read the data and you will know when it exits when your call passes the `WaitForExit()` call.

**Example:**

```
Process compiler = new Process();
compiler.StartInfo.FileName = "push.bat";
compiler.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
compiler.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
compiler.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;

var d = new StringBuilder();
compiler.OutputDataReceived += (o, e) => d.AppendLine(e.Data);
compiler.ErrorDataReceived += (o, e) => d.AppendLine(e.Data);
compiler.Start();
compiler.WaitForExit();
MessageBox.Show(d.ToString());
```

Comment: No problem! Thanks for actually accepting an answer rather than abandoning it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try "start /b SOMECOMMAND" invoking your command (or, alternatively, in your .bat file)